# Keep an object in array and remove remaining

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in which I have to keep an object always and remove everything else.

```
columnList = [];

//this object values remains same
defaultObject = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
}
this.columnList.push(defaultObject);

someMethod(){
    this.columnList = []; //emptying array

    //this object's values keep on changing
    anotherObject = {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2
    }

    this.columnList.push(anotherObject);
}
```

In the columnList array I need to keep the defaultObject always as first one and replace anotherObject based on some other logic. Here when I clear the array it removes defaultObject as well, which I want to prevent. I only want to remove anotherObject from array when the method call happens. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply: `this.columnList = [defaultObject];` instead of using an empty array? Obviously this depends on whether you still have access to the default object in that context.

Comment: Wow! it is very simple that I thought. Thanks guys.